# Purpose of Smart On FHIR and FHIR-NET-API

Tags: dstu2-fhir, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

Can anyone describe the purpose of the following tools and difference between them?

- [fhir-net-api](https://github.com/ewoutkramer/fhir-net-api)
- [smart-on-fhir](http://smarthealthit.org/smart-on-fhir/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fhir-net-api is the GitHub repository for the official .NET API for FHIR. You can use this API in your .Net solution. It provides you with the FHIR model, a FhirClient with methods to do CRUD and searches, parsing/serializing methods, etc.

SMART on FHIR is a platform that provides you with FHIR profiles and a way to more easily integrate apps with clinical data, including methods to do authorization. They also provide an app gallery, where you can host your own app.

So you can develop apps/applications with both and lots of work has been done for you already, but you'll still have to do the work to create your own app logic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

The fhir-net-api is a server side library? or a client side library?

Actually, we are going to make a full fledge EHR. We are taking .NET as development technology. Can you please suggest which way should I go?

Comment: The library provides you with the FHIR data model, parsers and serializers, which you can use to implement your server. There's also a client part to the library, but you can ignore that if you're not implementing a client. Perhaps for inspiration you can take a look at the [Spark server](https://github.com/furore-fhir/spark), which is also .Net based. This server uses parts of the API in its implementation.